# how to click element with _ngcontent and span buttontext using Protractor typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, protractor

I need help on creating a protractor typescript code, how do i click this button? it has _ngcontent and span buttontext, does anyone have an idea how to do this? code on the site is:

```
 <span _ngcontent-c6  class="braeting net-subheading-2"> ... </span>
 <button _ngcontent-c6  class="tulbar-button net-button" net-button>
   <span class="net-button-wrapper">
      <span _ngcontent-c6="">Login</span>
   </span>
  <div class="net-button-ripple net-ripple" matripple></div>
 <div class="net-button-focus-overlay"></div>
 </button>
```

i've tried the following below, i can't seem to make it work..

```
clickSignin = element(by.cssContainingText('tulbar-button net-button','Login'));
clickSignin = element(by.xpath('//span[@class="tulbar-button net-button"][_ngcontent-c6="Login"]'));
clickSignin = element(by.xpath('//span[@class="tulbar-button net-button"][text()="Login"]'));
```

then performed

```
clickSignin.click();
```

none of them seem to work.. and error says:
Failed: No element found using locator: By(xpath..... or by.cssContainingText....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Try this:

*note: your argument for cssContainingText is wrong*

```
clickSignin = element(by.cssContainingText('.tulbar-button.net-button','Login'));
```